# JSFiddle itself not working; can't find elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I have a super simple fiddle... but when I do an inspect element, `$("#cart table")` and frankly `$("#add")`, `$("#remove")`, `$("#cart")` all return null even though these items are on the page... what am I doing wrong?

(Consequently what's breaking is my line `$("#cart table").find("tr").length()`)
https://jsfiddle.net/qb3a6j31/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `length` is a property, not a function,

```
$("#cart table").find("tr").length
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qb3a6j31/2/)

Your full code would be,

```
$(document).on("click", "#add", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var next_item_number = parseInt($("#cart table").find("tr").length) + 1
  var item =
  '<tr>' +
    '<td>Item #' + next_item_number + '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
  $("#cart table").append(item)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You're not loading jQuery in your jsFiddle

2) This won't work

```
$("#cart table").find("tr").length()
```

...because there are no table rows available when you initially click the add button.

3) When you do have rows, it's `.length`.

I would be inclined to write it like this. It gets the rows, and if there are some uses `length`, otherwise `1`.

```
var $rows = $("#cart table").find("tr");
var next_item_number = parseInt($rows.length || 1, 10);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9zLzc88o/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `length` as a function but it is a property. Use `length` instead of `length()`

```
$("#cart table").find("tr").length
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qb3a6j31/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).length is not a function
```

`length` is a numeric property, not a function. Replace your code with this:

```
parseInt($("#cart table").find("tr").length)
```

And it will work. Note: You may want to add an explicit 10 radix parameter to `parseInt`.